# phantom_omni cannot rosmake

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

i am trying to rosmake but i get the message
make[3]: Entering directory `/home/alexandros/fuerte_workspace/sandbox/phantom_omni/build' Linking CXX executable ../bin/omni /usr/bin/ld: warning: libraw1394.so.8, needed by /usr/lib/libPHANToMIO.so.4, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link) /usr/lib/libPHANToMIO.so.4: undefined reference to` raw1394_destroy_handle'

i have installed all the dependencies needed and the libraw1394.
what should i do ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71710/phantom_omni-cannot-rosmake/) by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on ROS Answers with karma: 29 on 2013-08-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Locate libraw1394 and you create a simbolic link `sudo ln -s libraw1394.so.11 libraw1394.so.8`in that directory. In my case the directory was /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/

---

Originally posted by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) with karma: 20 on 2013-08-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [rem870](https://answers.ros.org/users/5383/rem870/) on 2013-08-23**:
great it compiled!. did you have to use the  JUJU Phantom Device Drivers ? (i have 12.04 ) i don't have the haptic device now and cannot rosrun it!

**Comment by [jalvarofa](https://answers.ros.org/users/5536/jalvarofa/) on 2013-08-26**:
Yes, I use de JUJU PDD with Ubuntu 12.04